# Admob ad not display on real android device

Tags: android, admob, ads, live

I am using admob ads for my app. I have taken default activity as admob activity from android studio and then I  have changed adunit id. When I have run in emulator, It was showing ad but while I was running same code in real device It was not showing anything, a blank screen was appearing. I am using samsung J7 and samsung duos to run apk. There was nothing showing, I searched different ways but cannot findout what was the wrong. Here is my code.
This is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    />
```

Here activity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
        + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111")
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
    Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

What I need to change for showing customised Live ads.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**
You added `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR`, therefore you can showing AdView(banner) in emulator, but you don't added to your real device id.

> `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` is **ad-unit-id** not device id.

**Solution**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting

Please add your real device id refer to link.

Comment: Is Id different for emulator and real device ?

Comment: @UmashankarB yes id is different for both.Remember to add a test device ID for each device that should request test ads. Device IDs are written to the system log by the Mobile Ads SDK, so you can find your device's ID by running your app and checking logcat.

Comment: Which id is required for live ads(custom ads),please  I am little bit confusion

Comment: I created own add in admob but I cannot display that ad in real device. What is procedure for display own ads.

Comment: @UmashankarB Do you see test ads on your real device now?

Comment: yes, I can see test ads when I am giving test id like .addTestDevice("906BEE36D8BBB116012044F7EAF88EAE"),  If I change with adunit id "ca-app-pub-9555621778445170/8998432441" I am getting real ads. But I cannot show my own ads, I created in admob. I changed this adunit id with new created id but not showing